# Swift not inferring enum type from other view controller directly

Tags: ios, xcode, enums, xcode10, swift4.2

I have declared some enum values in view controller and trying to access in another class, but for some enum I can infer directly but for other I need to use the class name. Sample code

```
class MyRootViewController: UIViewController {
    enum Animation {
        case left
        case right
        case top
        case bottom
        case none
    }
  //some code
}

class OtherViewController: UIViewController {
  enum Configurations {
        case config
        case version
        case type
    }
  //some code
}



 class Utility {
   func addConfiguration(_ config: Configurations) {
    //some code
    }

   func showAnimation(_ animation: MyRootViewController.Animation) {
   //Some code
   }
  }
```

Here in the second function of Utitlity if I declare like `func showAnimation(_ animation: Animation)` it throws error "Use of undeclared identifier Animation"

Why did in first method worked even though I didn't mention class but in the second one didn't?

Comment: It should not work in any case, I think you have some another class for `Configurations`, can you pls check and confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FYI:** `addConfiguration` is giving error.

[image: Error]

Please check in your `source code`, I am sure any `framework` is having `Configurations` `class` or `enum` is defined in your project.

That's it

Comment: Yes, it looks like one the framework in pod file had similar enum defined with the same name Configurations.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

please check your first function is not work.

it throws error "Use of undeclared identifier Animation"

so you have change your source code first.
thanks..